# Calculating energy release in MeV

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, nuclear-physics, binding-energy

I have the following questions, and would really appreciate you help towards finding the solution.

If .190 amu is converted into energy for every nucleus of U-235 undergoing fission, then calculate the energy release per nucleon in MeV.

U-235 has a mass of 235.0439299.
Given that it has 143 neutrons and 92 protons, then the following calculation:
$$(92\cdot1.007276)+(143\cdot1.008665)-235.0439299=1.864557u$$

$$1.864557 \cdot 931.494 \frac{MeV}{c^2} =1736.824MeV =  \frac{1736.824}{235}=7.39074MeV$$

Though, given the following calculation, i'm not sure where $0.190$ fits into this?

Furthermore, how do I calculate the difference between the many times of energy release between 1kg of U-235, compared with the combustion of 1kg of coal?

Answer (score 1):

The first and second line of numerical calculations you show pertain to the *binding energy* of $\mathrm{U}^{235}$ but that is not needed here. As 'Sentry' stated in his answer, the fission of $\mathrm{U}^{235}$ does not result in a bunch of scattered neutrons and protons but rather in a variety of fission-resulting atom pairs.

The question here is simply:

> If 0.190 amu is converted into energy for every nucleus of U-235
> undergoing fission, then calculate the energy release per nucleon in
> MeV.

The 0.190 amu is simply *a given* here, not something that needs to be calculated. A $\mathrm{U}_{235}$ nucleus has 235 nucleons, so the energy release per nucleon is simply:

$$\frac{0.190\mathrm{amu}}{235\mathrm{nucleons}}\times 931.5\mathrm{MeV/amu}=0.7531\mathrm{MeV/nucleon}$$

Answer (score 0):

In your calculation you take the mass of 92 single protons and 143 single neutrons and compare it to the mass of the U-235 nucleus. This is, you calculate the energy release if the U-235 nucleus exploded into 92 protons and 143 neutrons.

This is not what happens in nuclear fission. Rather, the uranium nucleus breaks into two medium-sized fragments, let's say for example a Cs-137 and a Rb-98 nucleus. So your calculation for the energy release would have to be the sum of the masses of these two nuclei minus the mass of the uranium nucleus. You'll see that the result is much, much lower. Look also how it's much closer to the 0.190 amu.

The problem here is that you don't always get the same fragments. Cs-137 and Rb-98 are just examples, but there are a lot of other possibilities and you can never say in advance which products you'll get (have a look at ["Fission product yield"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission_product_yield) for more information). This is where the 0.190 amu fit in. While you can't say how much energy will be released in an individual fission, you can average over many fission processes and get an average energy release per fission. This is your 0.190 amu.

PS: I've used mass and energy interchangeably. Both are the same anyway and in the process of nuclear fission this is even more visible than anywhere else.